# What are the maximal ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be the ring $ \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)$. Pick the correct statements from below:

$(1)$ $ \dim_{\mathbb{C}}R=3$,

$(2) $ $R$ has exactly two prime ideals,

$(3)$ $R$ is a UFD,

$(4)$ $(x)$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

**Answer:**

As any element of $ \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)$  if of the form $ax+b, \ a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $ax+b$ being irreducible, $ \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a UFD.

Thus option $(3)$ is correct.

Next,

Now any prime ideal of $ \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)$  must contain $ A=(x+i)/(x^2+1)$ and $B=(x-i)/(x^2+1)$. So these are the only two prime ideals.

Hence $(2)$ is correct.

Next,

the prime ideals $A,B$ are also maximal because

Since any element of $ \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is of the form $ax+b$, it has dimension $\leq 2$.

So the option $(1)$ is wrong.

But how to handle option $(4)$?

What are the maximal ideal?

Help me and check my results.

Comment: All maximal ideals are prime ideals.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, But all prime ideals are not maximal ideal in general.  Also how to show that $(x)$ is not maximal ideal?

Comment: You have already found all prime ideals...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, Can you check my works?  Also tell me how to show that $(x)$ is not maximal ideal

Comment: The UFD-statement is false. The ring isn't even a domain since $(x+i)(x-i) = x^2 + 1 = 0$.

Comment: Your solution to part (3) makes no sense. What does the statement have to do with being a UFD?

Comment: $(x)$ can't be a maximal ideal of $\mathbf C[x]/(x^2+1)$ because in $\mathbf C[x]$, the ideal $(x)$ does not contain $x^2+1$.

Comment: @Bernard Can you please explain your last comment?

Comment: @cmi: The prime ideals in the quotient correspond bijectively to the prime ideals in $\mathbf C[x]$ which contain the ideal $(x^2+1)$. Now the ideal $(x, x^2+1)$  is the ring $\mathbf C[x]$ since it contains $1$.

Comment: That's why $<x> = R$..@Bernard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$,
$$
\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)
\cong
\mathbb{C}[x]/(x+i)
\times
\mathbb{C}[x]/(x-i)
\cong
\mathbb{C}
\times
\mathbb{C}
$$
This immediately settles (1) and (3). It also helps to settle (2) and (4) because finding all ideals is easy.

Comment: so option $(2)$ only true